# Formatting Time (HH:MM:SS)

Tags: vb.net, string, date, time, formatting

I'm taking values from Numeric Ups and Downs for Hours, Minutes and Seconds.

The problem is that, for example, if the time for example is 9.15 am it will show as 9:15:0

What I want to do is format them so if any of the values(Hours, Minutes or seconds) is less than 10, it will add a 0 before the number so as the number shows as 09:15:00.

What I tried is this but it does not work:

```
Sub BtnSetClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        lbl8.Visible = True

        Dim nmTime As String = nmHour.Value.ToString + nmMin.Value.ToString + nmSec.Value.ToString



        lblST.Text.Format(nmTime.ToString, "HH:MM:SS")


        lblST.Text = (nmTime)

        lblST.Visible = True

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub BtnSetClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)          

    lbl8.Visible = True          
    Dim nmTime As String = nmHour.Value.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + nmMin.Value.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + nmSec.Value.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0')            

    lblST.Text = nmTime          
    lblST.Visible = True      
End Sub
```

Comment: Not to insult Tim but you've accepted the wrong answer, ho1's answer is the better way.

Comment: @Rene147 - No insult at all, just a statement of fact.  I believe I said much the same thing in my comment to ho1's answer :)

Answer (score 10):

You seem to be doing it a bit backward by converting everything to string multiple times, try something like this:

```
Dim ts As new TimeSpan(CInt(nmHour.Value), CInt(nmMin.Value), CInt(nmSec.Value))
lblST.Text = ts.ToString("HH:MM:SS")
```

The documentation for [TimeSpan.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632.aspx) is useful.

Edit: Updated the code to reflect Tim's comment about datatype.

Comment: Much neater than my suggestion :)

Comment: according to MSDN, `Value` is a decimal, so yes, OP will need to cast to Integer.

Answer (score 1):

try using the TimeSpan object, it should do all the hard work for you!

```
Dim nmTime As New TimeSpan(nmHour.Value, nmMin.Value, nmSec.Value)

lblST.Text = nmTime.ToString
lblST.Visible = True
```